Polarize and monitor a large resistor like device
goal
My goal is to design a board monitoring the resistance of a device which is basically a resistor (5-500 MΩ) in parallel with a capacitor (10-100 pF).
The device must be polarized (ie. the board I'm designing applies a -500 to +500 mV voltage across it).
What I have tried
I tried the following circuit:

A micro-controller (STM32G431) controls the polarization voltage through Vcmd. Since Vfb (FeedBack) = Vcmd, Vcmd is software defined to Vmiddle + the polarization voltage Vload.
The LTC6269 dual Op Amp has a fA range input bias, so the feedback current is negligible and the current through R1 is almost equal to the load current.
Knowing Vfb (=Vcmd) and the fixed R1 (ref) value, we measure Vctrl and compute the load current, then the load resistance.
To give some specific values, Vanalog=3.3V, Vmiddle=1.024V and the ADC reference voltage is 2.048V. Those voltages are provided by MCP1501-XX voltage reference chips.
Issues
In the real life, I face 2 main issues:
Noise
Vctrl is very noisy, even with a (small) 47kΩ R1 and a 50 kΩ potentiometer replacing the load. Here is the Vimg+ in yellow and Vcmd in cyan when the potentiometer is set to 12k.

I think I should wire another follower op amp to Vfb and use a differential acquisition (Vctrl - Vfb) instead of monitoring Vctrl alone to reduce the acquired noise but if the signal is that noisy, even in the tens of kΩ range, what would the outcome be with tens of MΩ?
Here is a part of the routing and the physical implementation:


I think I should have left more clearance between the ground plane in pale red and the Vfb track. I should also have put an uncut GND ring around Vfb but I prefer to ask before trying another circuit, this is my 6th iteration on this project...
R1 calculation
It is a bit tricky to set an ideal R1 value because the ADC voltage = f(device resistance) function is not linear. Here is a theoretical ADC voltage in black, 1.024V in blue, 2.048 V in red on the plan where x is the device resistance (the multiplier is omitted, it is the same for R1 and Rload) and y is the ADC voltage.


This curve changes a lot depending on the polarization voltage which is software defined by the user. This is my main concern about the R1 calculation.

All the sensitivity is "compressed" in the low resistance region: V(R=5) = 2V, V(R=50) = 1.22, V(R=500) = 1.13. This leaves a very small voltage difference spread across a large part of the curve where Rload > Rref. Because of the target application, this is the least important issue, but having a linear curve would be nice.

I'm afraid adding a software defined Rref resistor using analog switches would add capacitance, noise, etc.


Questions
Main question:

Are they some well documented circuits to polarize and measure a resistor-like circuit?

Some really good application notes explain the Wheatstone bridge or the transimpedance amplifier with tons of useful formulas but I saw nothing about this specific use case. From what I understand, the answers to this post suggest to use a circuit quiet similar to what I'm doing: How measure the voltage over a large resistance?
Side question:

Why is the circuit so noisy even with rather small resistors? I can see differences on the oscilloscope when my hand is close to the wires, I would expect this phenomena with smaller currents (when I'm testing with a 50 kΩ load resistor and a 47 kΩ R1).



this is my 6th iteration on this project...

Get the analog part working on a breadboard first. Not solderless breadboard, but a copper-clad FR4 with glued-down pads for components. QRPme sells those, they are very handy.
You should be using some sort of a custom MCU breakout board that makes it easy to connect the ground plane to the breadboard, and gives access to the DAC output and several ADC channels of input, along with VBUS ("5V" from USB).

I'm afraid adding a software defined Rref resistor using analog switches

The days of op-amps being so expensive you had to put switches around them are well over in most cases.
Use a few gain stages with different gains, all in parallel, sensing the output from your circuit. Then just select the one that's in range. This saves a lot of grief.
Do the switching with the ADC input multiplexer the MCU conveniently provides.
Make sure to use op-amps CMOS inputs that don't not have limits on differential voltage, i.e. both inputs can go rail-to-rail without increasing input current. That's typical of CMOS low-power op-amps these days anyway.


There's no decoupling on the supply voltage to the op-amp. The decoupling capacitor should be right next to the op-amp. You're using a 0.5GHz (!) op-amp. It's just luck that it's not oscillating.

The op-amp is overkill in terms of bandwidth. There are be plenty of low input current op-amps that are slower and otherwise perform just as well. They would be a better fit. They'll be quite benign compared to the part you're using.

Op-amp's bandwidth is not limited in any way, and the op-amp is not compensated for operation with high feedback impedance. There must be a capacitor, say 50pF, between (OUT) and (-) pins of the op-amp. That capacitor should be immediately adjacent to the op-amp's pins.


It is not clear how do you derive Vanalog from USB's VBUS. There may be decoupling or other problems there as well.
Let me redraw your resistance measurement circuit, since it is hard to read. Schematics are way more than graphical netlists used for PCB layout.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Observations:

Using a voltage reference for Vmid is overkill. Resistively divide the DAC reference down and optionally buffer it with an op-amp. The currents involved are so tiny that buffering is not needed, just decouple it. The exact value does not matter, a ±0.1V absolute error is fine.

You should be measuring both Vmid and Vctrl with the ADC. Connect Vctrl to one input, Vmid to another input, measure them sequentially and repeatedly, average the difference, take that as the output value.

As you noted, the dynamic range and response curves are not ideal.


The measurement circuit you're using is serviceable. We just need some extra gain when called for:

simulate this circuit

The difference between ADC2 and ADC0 is the voltage across the load. It is the independent variable used for characterizing the load's resistance-vs-polarization voltage.
ADC2-ADC0 can be used to control Vcmd in a closed loop in software. That loop can be slow and is not critical. Generally speaking, if you slowly sweep Vcmd across a range large enough so that the -0.5V to +0.5V across the load is swept, you're OK.

\$ADC_4-ADC_2 = +1 \times V(R_1)\$

\$ADC_1-ADC_2 = +2 \times V(R_1)\$

\$ADC_3-ADC_2 = -2 \times V(R_1)\$


Most likely, you'd want the gains of OA3 and OA4 to be higher than ±2, to get better use out of ADC's dynamic range.

I had the same LED lighting noise problem in my lab as Simon had mentioned. I replaced all the terrible noisemaker supplies with no-frills linear current sources fed from a USB power supply. It's quiet now :)

I have LED lighting in my lab that I have to switch off when performing noise measurements, since they radiate horrendous RF. I also have an LCD screen which produces similar crap even when switched off, due to RF from its power stand-by system of all things. I have to physically remove mains power.
Those problems mostly go away when grounded shield cans are installed around the sensitive parts of the circuit under test, but it makes for difficult diagnosis. My advice is to simply switch everything off, except what you need for testing, to distinguish between noise from external appliances and noise generated inside your own circuit.
PCB's conduct some current, which can really mess with your measurements, and you must take steps to prevent that. The trick is to ensure that high impedance, low-current traces (like your node Vfb) on the PCB are entirely surrounded by a conductor held at the same potential, called a "guard ring". With no potential difference between the sensitive node and any region of PCB immediately adjacent, no current can leave or enter that node from elsewhere.
Page 17 of the LTC6269 datasheet (fig. 12(a), top right) shows a suitable implementation, and that particular device even has pins you can use for this purpose, to facilitate guarding.
You will probably still require grounded shielding cans around the op-amp and its periphery, because those high-impedance paths are antennae for anything going on in the vicinity.

Source: www.precisionmicro.com
The example in datasheet fig. 12(b) illustrates an alternative method for measuring current in the load, by employing the op-amp as a TIA, which could also be viewed as an inverting amplifier:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The right-end of \$R_{LOAD}\$ is held very near 0V by the op-amp with negative feedback, and will therefore have \$V_{DAC}-0V=V_{DAC}\$ across it. Current through \$R_{LOAD}\$ is therefore:
$$ I = \frac{V_{DAC}}{R_{LOAD}} $$
In typical TIA fashion, all of that current passes through R1, and you have the following relationship, identical to the standard gain equation for an inverting amplifier:
$$ V_{OUT} = -V_{DAC} \times \frac{R_1}{R_{LOAD}} $$
There is the caveat that you can no longer connect \$R_{LOAD}\$ directly to ground at one end.
If you have more than a couple of centimetres of wire connecting your load, you'll need that wire to be shielded too. You may find a single-ended approach like this to be inadequate, and you should consider a differential amplifier instead, to deal with common-mode noise.
I notice that U2A has a single positive supply, meaning that it can't produce a negative output (or even zero, probably, the "rail-to-rail output" claim is a lie), and will not be able to reverse-bias the load.

Thank you for your answer, this was helpful. I had to toss coin to choose the one I should accept. I also have an LED strip above my desk but I turn it off every time I turn on the oscilloscope.
